# how do i give path to the controller action while ajax call from .js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, yii2-advanced-app

function sendData(types,data){

```
var datas={types:types,data:data};

console.log(datas);

 $.post({

       url:'../../controllers/news/ajax',

       data:datas,

       success:function(response){

           console.log(response)

       }

   });
```

}

this is my new.js file and need to do ajax call to action of newController.php file.

Comment: either `url: '<?php echo Yii::$app->request->baseUrl.'news/ajax'?>',`  OR `url: '<? echo Yii::app()->createUrl('news/ajax'); ?>'`

Answer (score 0):

you have to give full path in ajax like this

```
   var datas={types:types,data:data};
   console.log(datas);
   var url = '<?php echo base_url();?>';
   $.post({

   url:url+'/news/ajax',

   data:datas,

   success:function(response){

       console.log(response)

   }

  });
```

you can use base url function for that

Comment: POST http://localhost/hamroKhabar/backend/web/%3C?php%20echo%20base_url();?%3E/controllers/news/ajax 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0):

**You need to find workaround as below**

**.js** files are not parsed by asp.net mvc view engine, you cannot use any server side (c#) code in there. You can use [custom-data-attributes](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) to workaround this. create one `<div>` make it `display:none` and on set multiple `URLs` in different different data-attributes for all `ajax call` of your page. (like save,delete,load etc.)

```
<div id="allUrls" style='display:none' data-url-save="@Url.Action("SaveAction", "Controller")" 
          data-url-delete="@Url.Action("DeleteAction", "Controller")" ></div>
```

and after that in **New.js** file in ajax call you can access this div and get `url` as below

```
 var url = $("#allUrls").data('request-url-save');
       alert(url); // set this url in your AJAX call
```

Thanks

Comment: @johnsunam - please check above answer